# Understanding the stability of eulers method for a nonlinear system of differential equations and the relationship with the Jacobian.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eulers-method

So suppose I have the system of nonlinear differential equations:
$y'(t)=F(y(t))$

It looks like one equates the drive function to a local taylor approximation about $y(t_n)=y_n$ e.g
$F(y(t)) \approx F(y_n) + J(y_n)(y(t)-y_n)$, and now the stability analysis would be driven by the properities of $J$.

If I apply the euler method now:

$y_{n+1} = y_n + \Delta t F(y_n)$. The Jacobian term cancels. This is confusing to me because I believe the jacobian should infleunce this calculation for stability somehow, but I can't put the pieces together how.

Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Thank you for the input.

Comment: Why do you use the term "stability" when your question is more about the "truncation order" or "consistency order"? // Using the Jacobian gives you a Taylor method, or an exponential Euler method, depending on how you apply it. // Stability is about when the exact solution converges in some way and part, that the numerical solution replicate this qualitative behavior. A-stability is when a method satisfies this at least for linear systems with constant coefficients.

Comment: Hi Lutz, I'm trying to determine a stability criteria e.g. find the quantity in which $\Delta t $ must be less than or equal to that quality to make sure that the error does not grow as you are time stepping.  Consistency and stability of a numerical time stepping scheme does not neccessarly imply convergence to the true solution of the nonlinear ODE system.Consistency and stability does imply convergence if the problem is linear though.

Comment: The error will always be there and in the worst case grow exponentially. The convergence statement also applies to any non-linear DE, the only requirement is Lipschitz continuity.